# pass JSON dictionary and a char with argparse

Tags: python, json, dictionary, argparse

I'm trying to pass two arguments to python, one read-only JSON file and one char together. In fact I want the arguments both positional, but I couldn't do it either, so let the char one optional. At the end I will read the dictionary and the char will be my key.

When I try like below, the second argument is passed as None. I can't understand why it's empty. Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

python3 myProg.py dict.json -a

```
import json
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'program')
    parser.add_argument('json', nargs = 1, type = argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('-args', nargs ="?")

    arguments = parser.parse_args()
    dictionary = json.load(arguments.json[0])
    arg_start = arguments.args
```

Recieving this error:

> Namespace(args=None, json=[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='dict.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>])

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got the `json` file ok.  If you'd omitted the `nargs=1` you could have used:

```
dictionary = json.load(arguments.json)
```

`-args` is an `nargs='?'`.  That means it it is ok to omit an argument.  If not used at all its value will be the Actions `default` (currently `None`).

If provided as just `-a`, the value is the Action's `const` (also `None`).

If provided as `-a foo`, it will set that string.

If you'd define that `argument` as positional, plain 'args' (without the -) then it would have accepted the next string after the json file name.

Comment: I want to pass two positional arguments, without having any optional arguments. When I set add_argument like below, 
`parser.add_argument('args', nargs =2)`

I got this error message : the following arguments are required: args
I still don 't understand how I can pass two arguments

Comment: `python3 myProg.py dict.json a` this gives "error: the following arguments are required: args"

`python3 myProg.py dict.json a a` gives two `a` s.

`Namespace(args=['a', 'a'], json=[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='dict.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>])`

Comment: With `nargs=2`, the 'a a' input is the correct one.  Look at the usage line in the error message.

Comment: If you want `myprog.py jsonfile astr`, omit the `nargs` parameters.

Comment: problem solved when I wrote nargs = 1. I thought nargs was order of the argument, but apparently I was wrong. Thanks a lot or your help!